# Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reflection, activator

I am initializing a class at runtime using Activator.CreateInstance.
How do I loop through all the properties of the class that is initialized?
I get a compile-time error 'Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' to 'bool''

```
public class CustomOperations<T> where T : class
{
    public void AssignValues(int input)
    { 
        T newObject = default(T);
        newObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in newObject.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            //Getting a compile time error - Cannot convert type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' to 'bool'
            bool field = (bool)prop;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting the PropertyInfo object as a bool? There is an example of how to loop through it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo

Comment: How do you plan to _assign_ values dynamically? You won't know the property type at compile time, so it's not clear what trying to convert it to `bool` is doing. If you have a specific use case there's most likely a duplicate question that will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prop` is of type `PropertyInfo` if you want the actual value of `newobject`
you need to get the value of it.
I changed the code below(And added a security so it only gets propeties of type `bool`)

```
public class CustomOperations<T> where T : class
{
    public void AssignValues(int input)
    { 
        T newObject = default(T);
        newObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in newObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p=>p.PropertyType == typeof(bool)).ToList())
        {
            bool field = (bool)prop.GetValue(newObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `ToList()`? Also why `newObject.GetType()` you could just do `typeof(T)`

Comment: Yes the code could be more simplified but i tried to keep it as close als possible to the sample code